# Libgdx - maximum sprites

Tags: android, libgdx

Would the older phones work at 60 fps if I would draw around 300 sprites on screen. Collision would be checked only with the player! Would it work fine for older phones?

Comment: It's a general question. Can you provide more details about your game?

Comment: That's it! I have game objects made from small circles, and so about 300 circles are on screen each frame and each frame there is collision check for those 300 if they overlap with player! That is everything that would be happening each frame. Would older phones experience any lagg because of so many sprites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is no silver bullet for older devices and also 300 circles are too much for drawing, but here are some common tips for improving performance:

1. Use [Object Pooling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management)
2. Don't use `batch.begin()` or `batch.end()` too often in your render loop.
3. Don't draw or (maybe)check collision for those circles that are not in the viewport(screen).
4. Don't create new texture/sprite in your render loop.
5. Use [Texture Atlas](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer), also you don't need 300 textures for drawing all circles. You can use a same texture region for multiple circles.
6. Use Android Monitor for profiling your game.
7. Take a look at [android pref tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)
8. Don't use android emulator for testing your game :)
9. Maximum number of sprites in a single batch is 5460
10. Take a look at [performance tuning](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-textureregions%2C-and-sprite#performance-tuning) for sprite batch

Comment: 1: DONE, 2: MAX 2 CALLS, 3: DONE, 4: NEVER, 5: DONE, I'm also rotating most of the sprites, so that costs a little more. Also in a rare occasion there would be 250 max, but otherwise around 150-200. So I should be fine?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be fine

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi you wrote "300 circles are too much", did you mean "aren't"?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to go with LibGDX after seeing this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBiq2SGs93U

It may be helpful for you too.

Comment: No comment. Damn it beats its opponents! Actually boosted my level of confidence.